# How to copy specific rows to another sheet below black cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro to copy rows from one worksheet to another below cell that is colored black (manually) - if it is detected, otherwise just copy rows from first sheet to Sheet1 at the top. After many trials and errors I came up with that code:

```
Sub copytherows(clf As Long, lastcell As Long) 'clf - cell that marks the start, lastcell - ending cell
   
    Dim st As Long, cnext As Range
    Dim wshet As Worksheet
    Dim wshetend As Worksheet
    'st - start of looking up, cnext - range of lines, wshet - worksheet
Dim coprange As String
Dim cnextcoprow, cnextrow As Long
'variables for copying macro part
Dim rangehelper As Range
Dim TargetColor As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Dim Aend As Long
    Set wshet = Worksheets(1)
    Set wshetend = Sheets("Sheet1")
    wshetend.Cells.Delete
    
    For st = 1 To wshet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If wshet.Cells(st, "B").Interior.Color = clf Then 'has the color of interest
             cnextcoprow = st
            Set cnext = wshet.Cells(st, "B").Offset(1, 0)            'next cell down
            
            Do While cnext.Interior.Color <> lastcell
                Set cnext = cnext.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
            Loop
            st = st + 1
            
        End If
    Next st
  cnextrow = cnext.Row - 1
  
    coprange = cnextcoprow & ":" & cnextrow

Aend = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'set color is black
  TargetColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)


wshetend.Activate

  For x = 1 To Rows.Count
    If wshetend.Cells(x, "A").Interior.Color = TargetColor Then

      
      x = x + 1
       Set rangehelper = wshetend.Rows(x)
      wshet.Range(coprange).Copy wshetend.Range(rangehelper).Offset(1)
     
 Else
 wshet.Range(coprange).Copy wshetend.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 End If
 Next x
End Sub
```

When Macro is ran it displays an error(Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed on line :

```
wshet.Range(coprange).Copy wshetend.Range(rangehelper).Offset(1)
```

Sheet1 is for sure present in Workbook.
Edit as suggested by @FaneDuru:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWkp8.png) - in this image is my curret state of worksheet that is `wshet` in my macro and for example if I select (by checkboxes) section1 and section3, section3 should be in the place of black cell in section1 (the order of sections doesn't really matter to me) inside destination sheet ( I know I'm not good in explaining things like that).
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kJpC.png) - this should be end result of this macro

Comment: I am not able to understand what you try accomplishing... You say "copy specific rows to another sheet below black cell", which should mean that the respective "black cell" should be in the sheet where to copy below it. In your not working code you try matching interior cells in B:B with `clf`. What value does `cls` have? 0? Then, you try iterate up to another interior color, `lastcell`. What value this `lastcell` have? What color should it be? You do not mention anything about it in your question. I can only deduce that you do not want pasting below the black cell. Please, clarify that

Comment: At least, edit your question and show us **how you call the sub you show**, and better explain **in words** the process your code should follow. Saying that you try finding the first black cell in B:B, then determine the consecutive rows range **up to a second colored cell (you should tell us what color), to be pasted in the first empty cell of the other sheet, **will it be a correct understanding** of what you try accomplishing?

Comment: Added Edit as suggested by you @FaneDuru hoping to explain better the problem I'm having

Comment: I looked to the picture you placed but I still do not understand anything... **What is to be copied from that sheet**? And based **on what logic**. If you are not able to explain in words, at least represent somehow the respective rows range in the picture. In such a way we maybe will understand what is to be done. If you are not able to help us understanding what you try doing, nobody can help you, I am afraid... Do you try copying more such rows ranges? Why there are three black cells?

Comment: @FaneDuru  From the first sheet as shown in picture it is meant to be copied everything including: section cell ( marking start of section) rows between one section and another, and also the black cell (marking the end of section). If for example section1 and section 3 are selected, then section3 should be copied to the place where black cell is. Black cells were set to mark the end of sections and later to mark where next section should be copied so I could have for example twenty sections, and on the bottom of last section is the black cell marking the end.

Comment: I am even more confused than before... Should the code copy **selection**? You did not say anything about a selection in your question. Anyhow, if so, 1 and 3 are selected, based on what logic to choose section 3? What to be copied if section 2 and   15 are selected? And supposing that you make clear **what to be copied**, even if now it is not clear (at least, for me), where in the other sheet to be copied? Should it there be a black cell? If yes, do you know in which column will it be? Can it be in other column than A:A?

Comment: @FaneDuru In the wshet ( the sheet that has sections NOT selection) the sub should copy rows between SECTION1 and black cell in column A including the coloured cells named section1 and black cell. If I select (by CHECKBOXES) more sections then whn the macro does detect the black cell in column A, it copies next SECTION starting from black cell.

Comment: I thought I can help but I will abandon this idea. You are talking about black cells in column A, but in your picture the colored cells are in the second column you show. I do not understand what selecting by CHECKBOXES concept does mean,  I do not understand anything. I wish you success in solving your problem! Maybe somebody else will guess what you want. I am not able do do it.

Comment: @FaneDuru the column of black cells does not matter to me , it can be either A or B. selecting by checkboxes means that when I check the checkbox adjacent to section1 and section3 for example, those two sections will be copied to sheet1, with section3 being copied to starting point of  the black cell that was copied with section1 . Sorry for caps before but I was trying to distinguish the reasons you could not understand my previous comment.

Comment: **Where are these check boxes**? Did I miss them in the picture you try showing? Anyhow, should such check boxes exist on the row which represents the section start? Did you use them in your code and I also missed that? Are them o a specific column and you forgot showing them? Did you mention about these check boxes involvement in the rows to be copied range definition and I also missed that part? So, supposing that you clarify where these check boxes exist, should  the rows to be copied be the ones **starting from the first such ticked check box ROW, up to the next black cell**?

Comment: @FaneDuru checkboxes were just added now by me, sorry for the snip without them. They are meant to show the macro which sections should be copied, including the row with section number ending up to the next black cell if ticked. If the destination sheet already has a section ending with a black cell then another section should be copied below starting with black cell (so it does overwrite the black cell in destination sheet and makes it possible to copy more sections).

Comment: So, in less words, you thought about the check boxes after placing the question and you did not update it. Is that understanding correct? If so, please update your question with the new information and the logic of 'sections' limitation definition (the next black cell). Now, is it only a single such black cell in the destination sheet and all (ticked check boxes) sections should be pasted one after the other **after the found black cell**?

Comment: @FaneDuru in a moment I will update the post with information that is lacking. The whole idea of black cell is to mark in first sheet end of the section and in destination sheet mark the place where another section should be copied, furthermore each section has this black cell at the end (in first sheet) so when copied I can copy for example only section3 and section5 one below another.

Comment: It look OK now, but let me be sure that we started talking the same language: In the first sheet there are check boxes **on the row which starts each section** and the respective section (if its check box is ticked) is limited down **by the first black cell, inclusive**. It would be good to say **on which column** such a cell can be found. The ticked sections must be copied on the second sheet **below** the first found black cell (no matter in which column this one exists, one after the other. Would it be a correct understanding of what you try doing?

Comment: It would be also good to specify **in which column those involved check boxes exist**. In this way you can use some other check boxes for other reasons... And take care to use `ActiveX` check boxes type.

Comment: @FaneDuru They are in column G currently which is their preferred place to be

Comment: OK. They may be anywhere, but is good to be know where to be searching for them...

Comment: As I can see in your picture, the section ending black cells **can be found in B:B column**. Please take care to be there...

Comment: Please, test the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite confusing how you use the for loops.
In the first one you use it to check for the start -which is fine- but then you put a while loop in there which will end up in an endless loop once your st gets past your lastcell row, instead use

```
    ElseIf wshet.Cells(st, "B").Interior.Color = lastcell Then
        cnextrow = st
        Exit For
    End If
```

In the second for loop you copy the rows if you find the black cell but you don't exit the for loop, speaking of which, you delete all the cells in your wshetend so you'll always start at row 1. So either you don't want to delete all the cells in your wshetend or the for loop is unnecessary.

This is my testSub and it copies from the first sheet to Sheet2 after the cell with black background (black = 0) (commented out the delete cells)

```
Sub TestBlackCellCopy()
    Dim st As Long, cnext As Range
    Dim wshet As Worksheet
    Dim wshetend As Worksheet
    'st - start of looking up, cnext - range of lines, wshet - worksheet
    Dim coprange As String
    Dim cnextcoprow, cnextrow As Long
    'variables for copying macro part
    Dim rangehelper As Range
    Dim TargetColor As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    Dim Aend As Long
    Dim clf As Long, lastcell As Long
    clf = 5296274
    lastcell = 65535
    cnextcoprow = 0
    
    Set wshet = Worksheets(1)
    Set wshetend = Sheets("Sheet1")
'    wshetend.Cells.Delete
    
    For st = 1 To wshet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print (wshet.Cells(st, "B").Interior.Color)
        If wshet.Cells(st, "B").Interior.Color = clf And cnextcoprow = 0 Then 'has the color of interest
             cnextcoprow = st
        ElseIf wshet.Cells(st, "B").Interior.Color = lastcell Then
            cnextrow = st - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next st

    coprange = cnextcoprow & ":" & cnextrow

    Aend = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'unused variable?
    'set color is black
    TargetColor = 0


    wshetend.Activate
    
    For x = 1 To Rows.Count
        Debug.Print (wshetend.Cells(x, "A").Interior.Color)
        If wshetend.Cells(x, "A").Interior.Color = TargetColor Then
          wshet.Rows(coprange).EntireRow.Copy wshetend.Range("A" & x).Offset(1)
          Exit For
'        Else
'            wshet.Range(coprange).Copy wshetend.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

So you'll have to figure out what exactly you want, to delete the cells? Then it starts at row 1, then put a skip after a copy you place after the second for loop.
Something like this:

```
wshetend.Activate
    
    Aend = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 1 To Rows.Count
        Debug.Print (wshetend.Cells(x, "A").Interior.Color)
        If wshetend.Cells(x, "A").Interior.Color = TargetColor Then
          wshet.Rows(coprange).EntireRow.Copy wshetend.Range("A" & x).Offset(1)
          GoTo skipFor
        End If
    Next x
    wshet.Rows(coprange).EntireRow.Copy wshetend.Range("A1")
skipFor:
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does almost resolve my problem but the else in if that you put in comment block is for when in the destined sheet is no black cells and when I run the macro with clf in sub declaration and then setting the colour from section cell it crashes Excel completely

Comment: My sub does hardcode the colors I was working with, you'll have to adjust to what you're working with of course. Passing the colornumbers to your sub should be fairly easy the way you've been working with them previously. 
Like I said, I commented out your "wshetend.Cells.Delete" since otherwise you'll never have a black cell in your destination sheet (sheet1) and if you'll want to put several Sections in your destination sheet, use the second code-block as a replacement from "wshetend.Activate" onwards.

Comment: I get everything but when I run the macro it crashes my Excel even when secon block of code is inside my macro, where you suggested

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with F8 to see where the issue is?

Comment: Did this just now and it shows type mismatch on line:
wshet.Rows(coprange).EntireRow.Copy wshetend.Range("A1")

Comment: I just tried again and don't get a type mismatch. Are your variables still declared as before? Coprange is string? Also, wouldn't you always want to start adding the rows from lastrow+1 instead of looking for the blackcell? Since now it will always copy the rows from the first found black cell in A.

Comment: Is there data on the row with the black cell or can that part be overwritten? Because imo it would be easier to just work with lastrow. I'm starting to understand what you're trying to achieve but you can't AND clear the destination sheet AND populate with multiple sections if they're seperated, i.e. Section 1 and Section 3, with the same sub when passing values to your sub.

Comment: You could also work with a seperate sub that if you check a checkbox, it calls your sub with the necessary values and adds the rows from the last row and when unchecking, it deletes the rows from your starting color to the next black cell from your destination sheet.

Comment: everything is the same, only thing i changed is this:     Sub TestBlackCellCopy(clf As Long) and then when calling sub I'm giving it the colour of section i.e. TestBlackCellCopy rgb(253, 233, 217). In the row where the black cell is present there is nothing more no values, formulas, comments etc. I want to copy sections to another sheet one belowe another, it won't always be section1 and section2 but sometimes  section1 and section5 for example. When next section is copied it even must be to the black cell otherwise it won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way. It should work if you respected all what we set in the above discussion (check boxes in G:G, black cells in B:B for first sheet, and a black cell in any place of the second sheet:

```
Sub CopyRowsCheckBox_Black_limited()
   Dim wshet As Worksheet, wshetend As Worksheet, blackCell As Range, redCell As Range, rngCopy As Range
   Dim sh As Shape, chkB As MSForms.CheckBox, cellPaste As Range, pasteRow As Long
   
   Set wshet = ActiveSheet       'use here the sheet where from you need copying
   Set wshetend = wshet.Next  'use here the sheet where to copy
   
   'settings to make Find function searching for Interior color:
   With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear: .Interior.Color = vbBlack
        .Locked = True
  End With
  
  'find the black cell in the second sheet:
  Set cellPaste = wshetend.cells.Find(What:=vbNullString, After:=wshetend.Range("A1"), SearchFormat:=True)
  If Not cellPaste Is Nothing Then  'set the row where to copy first
        pasteRow = cellPaste.Offset(1).row
  Else
        pasteRow = 1
  End If
  
  'iterate between all shapes, found the ones being checkBoxes and being on column G:G, set the rows range and copy it:
   For Each sh In wshet.Shapes
        If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "CheckBox" And sh.TopLeftCell.Column = 7 Then
            Set chkB = sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object 'set the checkBox ActiveX object
            If chkB.Value = True Then                          'if it is checked
                 Set blackCell = wshet.Range("B:B").Find(What:=vbNullString, After:=wshet.Range("B" & _
                                                                                                   sh.TopLeftCell.row), SearchFormat:=True) 'find first black cell
                      Set rngCopy = wshet.Range(wshet.Range("B" & sh.TopLeftCell.row), blackCell).EntireRow 'set the rows to be copied
                      rngCopy.Copy wshetend.Range("A" & pasteRow): pasteRow = pasteRow + rngCopy.rows.count 'copy and update pasting row
            End If
        End If
  Next sh
  
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The range to be copied is the one between the checked check box and the first black cell in B:B column.

Important Note: **The top left corner of the check boxes must be inside of first series row**!

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Ok so this doesn't work for me as it just shows the msgbox and nothing is copied to second sheet, tried putting a black cell in destination sheet in  column B but that still doesn't help at all. Although I feel we have a good lead here. With my first attempt I wanted to make this sub flexible -meaning that if a checkbox is ticked then it is ran for section when button is pressed for example:
'sub save() 
If Worksheets(1).section1check.Value = True Then copytherows rgb(241, 228, 188) 
If Worksheets(1).section2check.Value = True Then TestBlackCellCopy rgb(241, 228, 188)
end sub'

Comment: @Marcin Jędrzejczyk This only means that **you did not respect the scenario we set above**! I tested the code! **Did you adapt the used sheets objects to your real ones**? I used generic active sheet and the next one. This is elementary, I think... Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If so,  I would like to connect to your computer to show you where you wrongly configured...

Comment: Unfortunately not....

Comment: I have a question about this : The top left corner of the check boxes must be inside of first series row! Does it mean that checkbox should be in the same row as section title ( section1, section2, section3 coloured cells in the picture 1 above) ?

Comment: @Marcin Jędrzejczyk  Of course! this is what we stated before! But not the square you can see! Edit the text box and see the whole object boundary. Then, **did you use ActiveX check boxes, as settled**? Din you know what ActiveX controls are? Besides that, AnyDesk is free and can be installed in maximum 5 minutes...

Comment: Basically I had two scenarios in mind when writing my code for this macro:
1. Destination Sheet is completely empty - we are adding sections one below another (the ones that got checkbox ticked) 
2.Destination Sheet has for example three sections, at the end of last one is this unfortunate "black cell" in coulmn B - we are adding one or more section at the place of "black cell" one below another
Having in my mind those scenarios I wanted to create more flexible macro that could be used many times.

Comment: @Marcin Jędrzejczyk Does destination sheet **have sectors**? Do you understand what you are saying? If you understand what is to be done and know explaining what you need, it will work perfectly. Now, I only regret that I did not respect a community clear rule: When a question is bad, you must not try answering it! You simple vote it down and inform OP that nothing is understood...

Comment: @Marcin Jędrzejczyk Is it so difficult to install AnyDesk? You may learn how to debug such a code and to better configure it, if necessary...